# formating number to currency with commas in jquery with slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the output formatted like 1,023,456.50  also for ui.values[ 0 ]
But it shows NaN.
Any ideas?

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range

```
$(function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
              animate: true,
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 10000000,
            step: 10000,
            values: [ 2000, 8888888 ],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#price-range" ).val( + ui.values[ 0 ].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ].toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );

            }
        });
        $( "#price-range" ).val( + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") +
            " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,") );
    });
```

For the original Code please see : [enter link description here](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)

Comment: Please post the HTML as well.

Comment: Well, this is the original code:

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine, except there is a syntax error.

```
$( "#price-range" ).val( +
```

Notice the **+** sign. You are also missing a few **$**'s in the text that you are outputting.

Example with the fixed error: http://jsfiddle.net/Dq9cP/